# Rowfilter with both AND and OR operator

Tags: c#, datagridview, rowfilter

I have a textfield where I can search three of my columns with the following rowfilter

```
table.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("CONVERT({0}, System.String) like '%{1}%' OR Subject like '%{1}%' OR Customer like '%{1}%'", "TicketID", searchTxtBox.Text);
```

I also have a `dateFrom` and `dateTo` DateTimePicker, and I want to show the search results based on results between these two dates. Obviously adding `AND date > AND date <` wont do. Anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: I thought between wasnt supported with rowfilter?

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition in `RowFilter` as:

```
" AND (#" + dateFrom.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "# <= dateInColumn AND #" + endDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "# >= dateInColumn)"
```

Comment: Something like this then? 
`table.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("CONVERT({0}, System.String) like '%{1}%' OR Subject like '%{1}%' OR Customer like '%{1}%' AND (#" + dateTimeFrom.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "# >= ticketDate AND #" + dateTimeTo.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "# <= ticketDate)", "TicketID", searchTxtBox.Text);`

Which doesnt work, if i pick two dates, it filters like it should, but when i do a search(code above) it ignores the dates and just searches the whole datatable. Im guessing the "OR" makes it ignore the dates? Any way to filter an already set filter?

Comment: Is there a way to do the like search without usin OR on 3 different columns?